# Getting WinMinimize to act on currently active window

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to write a hotkey to minimize the current window.

My current attempt is below and it does nothing.  I can't see how to make commands like WinMinimize act on the currently acitve window.

```
<^>!z::
WinMinimize,
return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the AutoHotkey help file, you can use the letter A to indicate the active window:

`WinMinimize, A`

Comment: Ah so it does. Missed that.....

Comment: This doesn't always work as intended. E.g. it sometimes sends the WM_MINIMIZE to modal dialog only. There should be a way to get the "main window" of the active window, and send minimize to there.